# Refactoring ES6 classes - call main class methods from other classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm currently working on a image slider and stuck on a problem with cleaning up and split my code into own classes.
This is a simplistic and minimal version of it, so constructors and other methods
were left out.

```
// Main class in slimSlider.js

import SliderUI from './slimSlider.ui';

class Slider {

  #addUI() {
        this.sliderUI = new SliderUI(this.opts,this.#sliderContainer,this.sliderWrapper,this.sliderElements);
  }

  #addUIEventsArrow() {
        this.sliderUI.arrowContainer.sliderButtonLeft.addEventListener('click', () => this.showPrevSlides());
        this.sliderUI.arrowContainer.sliderButtonRight.addEventListener('click', () => this.showNextSlides());
  }

  showNextSlides() {
        this.#slideTransition(false, 'right');
  }

  showPrevSlides() {
        this.#slideTransition(false, 'left');
  }

}
```

I want to transfer all methods that control the event listeners like `#addUIEventsArrow` from `Slider` to `SliderUi` class.
But how can i call main class methods like `this.showPrevSlides()` and `this.showNextSlides()` from `SliderUi` without having the class instance and not inherit to it?

```
// UI class in slimslider.ui.js

export default class SliderUI {

    #addUIArrows() {
        this.arrowContainer = {}
        this.arrowContainer.wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        SliderHelpers.setElClass(this.arrowContainer.wrapper,this.#controlCssClasses.container.arrowContainer.name);
        this.arrowContainer.sliderButtonLeft = this.#addUIArrowsSingle('left');
        this.arrowContainer.sliderButtonRight = this.#addUIArrowsSingle('right');
        this.controlContainer.appendChild(this.arrowContainer.wrapper);
    }

    // final result should be something like this
    #addUIEventsArrow() {
        this.arrowContainer.sliderButtonLeft.addEventListener('click', () => this.showPrevSlides());
        this.arrowContainer.sliderButtonRight.addEventListener('click', () => this.showNextSlides());
    }

}
```

Would be nice if somebody can help. Thank you

Comment: *how can i call main class methods like this.showPrevSlides() and this.showNextSlides() from SliderUi*, you don't. If  the `SliderUi` instance is a property of `Slider` then `Slider` should delegate all calls downwards to `SliderUi`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Absolutly make sense, but that's exactly my problem. 
Seems that I cannot delegate those method calls because they depending on other main class methods. In the end its just cosmetics to make the scripts clearer, but i think i maybe got a misconception in my class structure.